# Width of a DIV is nothing according to Javascript, why?

Tags: javascript, html, css

DIV's width is nothing according to DOM's Javascript.

This is such a simple little problem, but its well annoying.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            div#foot_wrapper{
                width:650px;
                height:20px;
                position:absolute;
                bottom:10px;
                background-color:#000000;
            }
        </style>
        <script>

            function align(div){
                                 alert(div.style.width); // ---------------- box pops up blank?
                div.style.left = (window.innerWidth/2) - (div.style.width/2);       
            }
        </script>

    </head>

    <body onload="align(document.getElementById('foot_wrapper'))" onresize="align(document.getElementById('foot_wrapper'))" >

        <div id="main">
        </div>

        <div id="foot_wrapper">
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

Try [`div.offsetWidth` <sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetWidth) instead of `div.style.width`.

The [`style` <sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.style) property only reflects the styles that were set inline on an element (using the `style` attribute on the element).

See also [Javascript - Get Style <sup>Quirksmode</sup>](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html)

*(For the best results you could use a library like [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/width/). The authors have already worked around the possible browser differences and quirks, so you won't have to deal with those.)*

Comment: But offsetWidth isn't supported in older IE browsers is it?

Comment: It is [supported even in IE 5.5](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#t34). It is originally a Microsoft thing.

Comment: Im getting an Invalid Argument error?! Its works in Chrome though:)

Comment: @user965369 Could you produce a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) test case? In which IE does it give this error?

Comment: Its the same as the code above just width div.width.style changed to div.offsetWidth

Comment: OK, I did it for you. [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y6e8m/1/). Works fine on my IE9. Don't forget that we're trying to solve *your* problem here.

Comment: Okay, your problem is that `window.innerWidth` is not supported in IE <9. Try `document.documentElement.clientWidth` for IE 8 and less.

Answer (score 2):

The style property gives you the style assigned directly to the element, not the styles that are applied from a style sheet, or inherited.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `style` DOM attribute contains only CSS properties defined inline. If you'd use `<div style="width: 650px;">`, you'd see correct result. For dimensions, use `innerWidth`/`clientWidth`, other properties can be read using `window.getComputedStyle()` (modern browsers) or `currentStyle` DOM attribute (IE<=8). Both behave a bit differently - if you use `width: 1em`, `getComputedStyle` returns `16px` and `currentStyle` returns `1em`, but it should be enough for some simpler tasks.